# Is there a way to programmatically extract all translatable text from source code?

Tags: rust, internationalization

I am looking for how to translate text in Rust source code. I have found the gettext-crate, but is there a way to programmatically extract all translatable texts from source code?

I want to do something like this:

```
rust_i18n extract -outdir=out.json -format=json MySampleProject
```

Which would then give me a list of all translatable texts that were used in the project and store them in out.json. (Similar to [goi18n](http://nicksnyder.github.io/go-i18n/) for golang.)

Alternatively, is there an easy way to get the AST for a project, so I could wrap all texts in a custom struct and extract usage of that struct from the source files associated with a project? Is there a better solution?

Comment: You can use crates like [syn](https://crates.io/crates/syn) to parse Rust code.

Comment: Your question ultimately seems misguided. How would such a tool differentiate between string literals that should be translated and those that should not? Pretending that internationalizing an application is as easy as translating text does a disservice to an entire profession (and many languages!). As an "Easy" example, [languages have different concepts of pluralization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Localization/Localization_and_Plurals).

Comment: I will look at syn, thanks for that. Regarding issues like pluralization - they are independent of my question. It soley is on how to extract translateable strings out of the source code such that none are missing. To enable differentation to string literals you can define a custom type (e.g. "TranslateableString") that encapsulates a string. Usage of this type then can be found by the extractor. The actual translation still needs to be done by methods that can handle things like pluralization. Again, this is just so no strings are accidentally forgotten during translation.